# Mutable IORef-based factorial example in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Here is my attempt to write the infamous factorial using `Data.IORef`.

```
import Data.IORef

xgo accRef nRef = go where
  go = do
    acc <- readIORef accRef
    n <- readIORef nRef
    writeIORef accRef (acc * n)
    writeIORef nRef (n - 1)
    if (n > 2) then go else readIORef accRef
       
facM n = do
  accRef <- newIORef 1
  nRef <- newIORef n
  xgo accRef nRef
```

This code is supposed to be an example for dummies on how to use IORefs, so certainly I want to keep it simple -- e.g. no tuples and no lens. But the whole `xgo` thing seem artificial. Can we have `xgo` defined within `facM`? What is the most idiomatic way to write IORef code like this (of course I don't mean avoiding `IORef`, we all know the `fac n = prod [1..n]` solution here).

Upd: I got it to:

```
facM n = do
  accRef <- newIORef 1
  nRef <- newIORef n
  let xgo = go where {
    go = do
      acc <- readIORef accRef
      n <- readIORef nRef
      writeIORef accRef (acc * n)
      writeIORef nRef (n - 1)
      if (n > 2) then go else readIORef accRef
  }
  xgo
```

So there are no second `accRef`/`nRef` anymore, but there is still this xgo/go separation. Somehow I can't get `xgo = do { ... }` working without an intermediate `go`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there a bug, if not a very significant one - 0! is meant to be 1, but the current code returns 0. Checking if n > 1 *before* you do any multiplication would get around this.

Second, since `acc` is only ever used for updating `accRef`, I feel it might be cleaner to use `modifyIORef` instead of a `readIORef` followed by a `writeIORef`. This wouldn't apply to `nRef`, though, since `n` is actually used in multiple places

Also, I'd like to see explicit type signatures added to any top-level functions (`facM` and, in the original code, `xgo`). I find that knowing the exact type of a value often makes it much easier to understand what it is and why.

Finally, you mention being able to merge the separate `xgo` function into `facM`, but ended up having to also have an effectively identical `go` function to make it work. I *think* that might've been you running into haskell's notoriously confusing indentation rules. For instance, the following *won't* work:

```hs
import Data.IORef

facM :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> IO a
facM n = do
  accRef <- newIORef 1
  nRef <- newIORef n
  let go = do
    n <- readIORef nRef
    if n > 1 then do
      modifyIORef accRef (* n)
      writeIORef nRef (n - 1)
      go
    else readIORef accRef
  go
```

because the content of that `do` block is to the left of the name it is bound to (`go`). However, either of the following *will* work, because the block is indented *further* than the name it is bound to:

```hs
import Data.IORef

facM :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> IO a
facM n = do
  accRef <- newIORef 1
  nRef <- newIORef n
  let
    go = do
      n <- readIORef nRef
      if n > 1 then do
        modifyIORef accRef (* n)
        writeIORef nRef (n - 1)
        go
      else readIORef accRef
  go
```

```hs
import Data.IORef

facM :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> IO a
facM n = do
  accRef <- newIORef 1
  nRef <- newIORef n
  let go = do
        n <- readIORef nRef
        if n > 1 then do
          modifyIORef accRef (* n)
          writeIORef nRef (n - 1)
          go
        else readIORef accRef
  go
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish but you can replace explicit loop with `mfix` from [`Control.Monad.Fix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Fix.html).

```
import Data.IORef
import Control.Monad.Fix (mfix)

facM :: Int -> IO Int
facM n = do
  accRef <- newIORef 1
  nRef <- newIORef n
  mfix
    (\loop _ -> do
      m <- readIORef nRef
      acc <- readIORef accRef
      modifyIORef accRef (* m)
      modifyIORef nRef (subtract 1)
      if m > 2 then loop else readIORef accRef
    )
    undefined
```

This has scary `undefined` (which can be replaced by `()`) so definitely not a good example for dummies.

---

Or like this if you want to confuse them even more:

```
facM :: Int -> IO Int
facM n
  = newIORef (n, 1)
  >>= mfix (\loop ref -> do
    (m, acc) <- readIORef ref
    writeIORef ref (m - 1, acc * m)
    if (m > 2) then loop else pure (acc * m)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to essential hints by @sara-j, I ended up with the following:

```
import Data.IORef
import Control.Monad
       
facM nn = do
  accRef <- newIORef 1
  nRef <- newIORef nn
  let
    go = do
      n <- readIORef nRef
      when (n > 1) $ do
        modifyIORef accRef (\x -> x * n)
        modifyIORef nRef (\x -> x - 1)
        go
  go
  readIORef accRef
```

The code works well as an example for dummies because it corresponds to the following imperative code:

```
function facM(nn) {
  let acc = 1
  let n = nn
  while (n > 1) {
     acc *= n
     n -= 1
  }
  return acc
}
```

And moreover, we can then learn to abstract the loop away:

```
whileM cond block = go where
  go = do
    x <- cond
    when x $ do
      block
      go
```

(and this is what `whileM` from `monad-loop` already does)